# Use of eBay API in PHP to retrieve My eBay information

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am on working on a personal project to write a PHP website which will allow me to easily track all my purchases/bids/watch list on eBay. As you know, purchases which are older than 2 months (I think) can't be seen on eBay; but I would still like to keep track of them. So I would be using the eBay API's to retrieve the information and then write it to my database.

My question is: which API's do I use to retrieve the information I mentioned? Or better still: would you know any script or website or anything that already does what I'm trying to do, even if partially?

Thanks in advance,

Yusuf

Comment: Is the question irrelevant? Or already addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at [eBay API](http://developer.ebay.com/), you can use it to retrieve your information. For example, in java you can follow this [guide](http://developer.ebay.com/quickstartguide/) which also includes sample PHP code.

Comment: oh, seems like I didn't look closely enough; thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I've also thrown some [example code up](https://github.com/iloveitaly/ebay-php/blob/master/eBayCommon.php) which includes searching active items in a user's profile