# Get my eBay listings with PHP using eBay API

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I've been reading through the eBay Developer Network and for the life of me can't figure out how to do the *simple* task of retrieving all listings from an eBay User (me) via their API.

Can anyone help me out on achieving this.

Thanks a lot.

Edit:

I have tried using HTTP method of:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetUser&appid=APPID&siteid=3&UserId=USERID
```

But this hasn't given me any luck.

Mainly with the PHP Methods, I've tried reading up on EBATNS but with no luck could I start coding to produce something small.

I have also looked at [Use of eBay API in PHP to retrieve My eBay information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674788/use-of-ebay-api-in-php-to-retrieve-my-ebay-information) and that didn't really help me all that much either.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: there are loads of examples here -> http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/howto/index.html complete with source

Comment: Do you have some links to the necessary docs etc.?

Comment: Sandeep, give it a bash - loads of people here willing to help you if you supply a bit of code `:-)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of eBay API in PHP to retrieve My eBay information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674788/use-of-ebay-api-in-php-to-retrieve-my-ebay-information)

Comment: @halfer as I said I couldn't get any luck on proper code as I couldn't figure out where to start. I've been trying out on the http web request (as in my question) but can't get listings for users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone needs the answer to this one I have figured it out after a day of research.

> http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SECURITY-APPNAME=**PRODUCTION-APPID**&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&itemFilter(0).name=Seller&itemFilter(0).value(0)=**USERNAME**&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=10&keywords=